# GraphQL Schema Design (.net)

Tags: c#, asp.net, graphql

I recently wrote a very simple application in which I used asp.net & GraphQL.When I wrote classes for queries/mutations, I tried to adhere to the principle of single responsibility and write a separate classes for each entity, for example, CategoryQuery/Mutation, TodoQuery/Mutation, UserQuery/Mutation, etc. Then I combined these queries into a single RootQuery and my graphql queries became a bit more complex than they were before.The problem is that I've seen a lot of tutorials where authors write all Query/Mutation in one class. Usually, the authors used 2-3 types and their Q/M class didn't look bad, but if there are a lot of entities in the project, then this class will grow very much and it will be difficult to maintain. However, with this approach, graphQL queries look simpler, especially if you use pagination and so on. So I can't decide which approach is better. Also, I would like to know if there are any other solutions that solve this problem

## The first approach (with separation):

```
public class CategoryQuery: ObjectGraphType
    {
        
        public CategoryQuery()
        {
                    Field("category").Resolve(...return smth);
            // Fied().Resovle
                    // Fied().Resovle
                    // Fied().Resovle
                    .........
        }
        
    }
```

```
public class TodoQuery: ObjectGraphType
    {
        
        public TodoQuery()
        {
                    Field("todos").Resolve(...return smth);
            // Fied().Resovle
                    // Fied().Resovle
                    // Fied().Resovle
                    .........
        }
        
    }
```

```
public class RootQuery:ObjectGraphType
{
    public RootQuery()
    {
        Field<TaskQuery>()
            .Name("todoQuery")
            .Resolve(_ => new { });

        Field<categoryQuery>()
            .Name("categoryQuery")
            .Resolve(_ => new {});
    }
}
```

## GraphQl queries will look like this:

```
query{
  todoQuery{
     todos{
       id,
       title
     }
  }
}
```

## The second approach (without separation):

```
public class RootQuery:ObjectGraphType
{
    public RootQuery()
    {
         //Todo
         Field("todos").Resolve(...return smth);
            // Fied().Resovle
                    // Fied().Resovle
                    // Fied().Resovle
                    .........
         //Category
         Field("categories").Resolve(...return smth);
            // Fied().Resovle
                    // Fied().Resovle
                    // Fied().Resovle
                    .........

    }
}
```

## GraphQl queries will look like this:

```
query{
  todos{
    id,
    title
  }
}
```